# Command text doesn't work= text won't or partially show

Tags: r, text, plot, graphics

For some strange reason the text command doesn't show all the words. Here's my df and code:

```
library(reshape)
library(coda)
install.packages("coefplot2",
               repos="http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/bolker/R",
                type="source") #modified
library(coefplot2)

predictor <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5")
coef <- c(0.0000000, -0.2253459, -0.7849048, -0.9388088, -1.1509515)
CI <- c(0.0000000, -0.8570941, -0.6416209, -0.6990803, -0.6287817)

df <- data.frame(predictor, coef, CI)    
        df$predictor <- as.character(droplevels(df$predictor))


par(mfrow = c(5,2))
coefplot2(df[, 3], df[, 2], varnames= df[,2], CI=1,h.axis=F
          , xlim=c(-3.5, 1.5), main="", mar=c(1,6,2,1), cex.var=1, cex.pts=1.5, pch.pts=16, lwd.2=1, frame.plot=T)

mtext(expression(paste(bold("X"))),cex=0.8, adj=0,line = 2.3)
text(-3.65,5,"E",cex=0.8,adj = c(0,0.6)); 
text(-3.65,4,"BE",cex=0.8,adj = c(0,0.6));
text(-3.65,3,"BC",cex=0.8,adj = c(0,0.6));
text(-3.65,2,"AC",cex=0.8,adj = c(0,0.6));
text(-3.65,1,"A",cex=0.8,adj = c(0,0.6));
```

There are 8 more plots of these so that's the reason why par(mfrow = c(5,2)) is coded this way. But for some reason not all the letters are shown.. Looks like a bug to me.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You are importing many packages. Are they indeed needed to demonstrate this example?

Comment: My bad. Deleted the unecessary packages

Comment: OK, now please provide enough data to give a reproducible example. :)

Comment: Done! Still don't have a clue what the problem is. If I produce one plot at the time (par(mfrow = c(1,1)) the letters do show, but this is not what I want as the end product

Comment: It would appear there's problems with margins (mar, mai). If you're not looking for a too flexible solution for various models, I would opt for a ggplot2 result...

Answer (score 0):

I find `ggplot2` more than suitable for presenting the results.

```
library(ggplot2)
sds <- 1
text.add <- data.frame(text = c("E", "BE", "BC", "AC", "A"), y = c(-3.6), x = 5:1)

(p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = predictor, y = coef)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = coef - sds * CI, ymax = coef + sds * CI)) + # adds CIs
  scale_x_discrete(labels = df$coef) + # sets vertical labels
  geom_text(data = text.add, aes(x = x, y = y, label = text)) + # adds text to the left side
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank(), # clears x axis
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  coord_flip() # flips everything
ggsave("onefig.png", width = 4, height = 2))
```

[image]

If you have several plots, one way is to combine them using `grid.arrange` (some tweaking still required).

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, p1, p1, p1, ncol = 2)
```

[image]